# time x axis in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here, x-axis is the time axis, with following code I see x-axis little bit displaced on right side. Any idea why does it happen? And how can we fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pad = 100;
    var width = 700;
    var height = 400;

    var dateString=["2014-02-17","2014-02-18","2014-02-19","2014-02-20","2014-02-21"];
    var value=[0,1000,2000,3000,4000];
    var y_extent = d3.extent(value,function(v){return v});
    var x_extent = d3.extent(dateString,function(ds){return new Date(ds)}); 
    console.log(x_extent,y_extent);

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain(x_extent)
            .rangeRound([pad,width-(2*pad)]);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(y_extent)
            .range([height-pad,0]);

       var svg =d3.select(".draw")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height);

    var x_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.days,1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b"));

        var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class","x axis")
            .attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-pad)+")")
            .call(x_axis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class","y axis")
            .attr("transform","translate("+pad+",0)")
            .call(y_axis);

    for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("cx", xScale(new Date(dateString[i])))
            .attr("cy",yScale(0))
            .style("fill", "red");  
    }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="draw">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is an example fiddle of the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/vucvjrun/1/)

Comment: Actually this is a problem with the `Date` object parsing based on your timezone. For example in my timezone is states: `[Sun Feb 16 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (US Eastern Standard Time), Thu Feb 20 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (US Eastern Standard Time)`. Meaning other than going from the `17th` to the `21st` directly, it's doing late `16th` to early `20th`.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the `Date` object is taking the date and adjusting it based on your local time. This is actually what is causing the offset, since the real dates will slightly vary. An easy way to fix that is to use `interval.utc`, so it will take times intervals in UTC rather than local time. So for `var x_axis` rather than having:

```
.ticks(d3.time.days,1)
```

Replace it with:

```
.ticks(d3.time.days.utc,1)
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vucvjrun/)